Unable to query a view in Google BigQuery
When I am trying to query a view in BigQuery I am getting the following error. What does it mean?
Method ExecuteBatchQuery of service cloudclient-pa.googleapis.com is visibility restricted, but Chemist visibility check was unavailable.


Hi @user19930511, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
